# Auto-adjust an image relative to window's height with CSS

Tags: html, css

this may look a silly question, but I'd appreciate some help anyway.

I have a HUGE image which I need to adjust to 1/3 of the window's height automagically with CSS. I need to keep its width proportional. I'd like not to use JavaScript if possible.

Can you give me some hints???

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, add the CSS property: `height:33%`

This is unfortunately as close as we get to 1/3 the height of the window. This assuming your picture's parent node is the body, or also has 100% height of the window.

You may need to add:

```
html, body {
    height:100%
}
```

As well as to any elements the picture is in.

Comment: That works for any direct child of the body element, but I need to put my image a couple <div>s deep inside that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the css position attribute

```
#some-container {height:600px; position:relative;}


/* this will make your image height 200px */
#some-contained-image {position:absolute; height:33%}
```

I've put together a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ggx3/)

Once you have an element marked with position relative then you can use position absolute on an element it contains (regardless of depth). Counter-intuitively the position of the item marked absolute will be determined relative to the container marked relative.

This of course will effect a lot more than just height so I can't really recommend you do this. You probably will need to use javascript to get what you want.